# Tensorflow cifar synchronization point

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

Reading https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/image/cifar10/cifar10_multi_gpu_train.py for function `average_gradients` the following comment is provided : `Note that this function provides a synchronization point across all towers.` Is function `average_gradients` a blocking call and is what is meant by `synchronization point` ?

I assume this is a blocking call as in order to calculate the average of gradients each gradient must be individually computed ? But where is the blocking code that wait's for all individual gradient computes ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `average_gradients` by itself is not a blocking function. It could have been another function with tensorflow operations and this would still be a synchronization point. What makes it blocking is the fact that it uses the argument **`tower_grads`** which depends on all the graphs created in the previous for loop.

Basically what happens here is the creation of the training graph. First, in the for loop `for i in xrange(FLAGS.num_gpus)` several graph "threads" are created. Each looks like this:

calculate loss --> calculate gradients --> append to `tower_grads`

Each of those graph "threads" is assigned to a different gpu through `with tf.device('/gpu:%d' % i)` and each one can run independent from each other (and will later run in parallel). Now the next time `tower_grads` is used without a device specification, it creates a graph continuation on the main device, binding all those separate graph "threads" into a single one. Tensorflow will make sure that every graph "thread" that is part of the creation of `tower_grads` is finished before running the graph inside the `average_gradients` function. Therefore later when `sess.run([train_op, loss])` is called, this will be the synchronization point of the graph.